# How to override 2nd managed package application home page content?

Tags: managed-package, tab, home-page-component, flexipages, page-override

I have the problem after 2nd gen package installs.
All Settings with overriding ar lost. Code example is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <brand>
        <headerColor>#222222</headerColor>
        <logo>logo</logo>
        <logoVersion>1</logoVersion>
        <shouldOverrideOrgTheme>false</shouldOverrideOrgTheme>
    </brand>
    <formFactors>Small</formFactors>
    <formFactors>Large</formFactors>
    <isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>false</isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>
    <isNavPersonalizationDisabled>false</isNavPersonalizationDisabled>
    <isNavTabPersistenceDisabled>false</isNavTabPersistenceDisabled>
    <label>Test label</label>
    <navType>Standard</navType>
    <profileActionOverrides>
        <actionName>Tab</actionName>
        <content>flexi_page_api_name</content>
        <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
        <pageOrSobjectType>standard-home</pageOrSobjectType>
        <type>Flexipage</type>
        <profile>My Custom Profile Name</profile>
    </profileActionOverrides>
    <tabs>standard-home</tabs>
    <tabs>standard-Account</tabs>
    <tabs>standard-Event</tabs>
    <tabs>standard-Feed</tabs>
    <uiType>Lightning</uiType>
    <utilityBar>Test_UtilityBar</utilityBar>
</CustomApplication>
```

So after package installing there are no effect for profile overriding.

I got the [docs link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profileactionoverride.htm) where

> **ProfileActionOverrides** aren’t supported in packaging. They’re supported in change sets, but you have to add them manually.

Is any opportunity to reach the goal automatically or should I doing assign flexipages manually each time?

Thanks!